# container with overflow:hidden needs to have one image's overflow visible

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to make this orange box pictured here:

[image: orange box]

Visible like its pictured here:

[image]

The image is inside a container with other images that need their `overflow:hidden`.
I tried setting the images div to `overflow:visible !important` but it makes no difference.

Putting the image outside of the container leads to issues when the window is resized and doesn't move with the container so I feel it is needed to be set inside the container but doing that leads to issues specified above.

sorry if the code is formatted weird im new.

```css
.container {
  margin: 2% 20%;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* text-align:left; */
}

.box-image {
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 184px !important;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9rem;
  left: -7rem;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <!-- box image here -->
      <svg class="box-image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share the code and images for this problem. Its hard to solve something just by looking at a picture

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui ok ive added the html and css

Comment: @rachel I have not tried on your code, but i think the problem is not about overflow but z-Index. Have you try to set a higher z-Index for the orange box to let it appear on the topmost layer?

Comment: @jingXian yes its on z-index:3; while the other images are 2 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a possible fix for you. Keep 2 elements inside your container. 1 will be the SVG that is your box container (to whom you do not want `overflow: hidden` to apply) and the other will be another element with a class `.wrapper`.

Once you apply `overflow: hidden` to an element, you cannot pick and choose which children of that element will be allowed to stay outside the boundaries. That's where the `.wrapper` element comes in. Set `.wrapper` to be the same height, width and border radius as `.container`, and apply `overflow` to `.wrapper` instead of to `.container`.

What this will do is allow the one element outside `.wrapper` to go outside the boundaries of container, but everything within `.wrapper` will remain inside `.container`.

I've inserted a snippet below that you can run:

```css
.container {
  margin: 2% 20%;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
  /*   top: 50%; */
  /*   left: 50%; */
  /*   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  width: 80% !important;
  /*   overflow: hidden; */
  /* text-align:left; */
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: inherit;
}

.box-image {
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 184px !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /*   bottom: 9rem; */
  left: -7rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <!-- box image here -->
    <svg class="box-image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <svg class="image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
      <svg class="image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
      <svg class="image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
      <svg class="image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
      <svg class="image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
      <svg class="image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
      <svg class="image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <defs>
                <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
                  <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
                  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                  <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
                </filter>
                <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
              </defs>
              <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
                  <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
                  <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
                </g>
                <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
                <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
                <path
                  d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911"
                  fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
              </g>
            </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've copied the same SVG a bunch of times inside the wrapper element to show how this works. Both `.wrapper` and the `.box-image` have borders for easier distinction.

You may notice that I've given `.wrapper` a `height: inherit`. This is because I want it to inherit its height from `.container`. However, since wrapper actually resides inside `.row` and not `.container`, I had to create a helper class `.h-100` which basically tells row to assume the full height of container, and the row's height will be picked up by `.wrapper`. If you'r using Bootstrap, which I suspect you are, based on the naming convention of classes, `.h-100` is already an existing class there, so you won't have to define it yourself.

**EDIT:**

I saw your code on github. You just need to make a few more modifications to this code to have it work there.

In index.html, your structure will be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
    <!-- box image here -->
      <svg class="box-image" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> ... </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- overflow hidden images  -->
      <div class="col"> ... </div>
      <div class="col accordion-column"> ... </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For your CSS:

```css
/* Get rid of left and right padding for rows */
.row {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Remove overflow from container */
.container {
  margin: 2% 20%;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80% !important;
}

/* Add the wrapper styling */
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;  
  padding-left: 100px !important; /* This is padding that was previously in .row */
  padding-right: 100px !important; /* This is padding that was previously in .row */
  padding-bottom: 65px;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex; /* This is important */
}

/* Change box placement dependancy to top, instead of bottom. This will
make sure that the box doesn't lose its position at resize. You can test it with bottom as well to see the difference.
*/
.box-image {
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 184px !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17rem; /* This is new */
    /* bottom: 9rem; */
  left: -7rem;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Pay close attention to how your HTML will be restructured. I'm also inserting a picture of how this will look below, since the entire code is too long.

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: when i tried this it threw off the accordion i have to the right of the images. is there any way to have the box-image outside of the container but when a user resizes the webpage the image will reposition along with the container ?

Comment: I'll need to have a look at the accordion and its css, to see how it may be interfering with this

Comment: i have the code up on github https://github.com/rachelharu/FAQAccordionCard

Comment: omg thank you so much! I have been trying to fix this issue for the past week.

Comment: @rachel Glad to hear that. Also, you'd do me a favor by hitting the accept button :)